# Do I need "will" in "After I'm done working I will have no plans"?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

buddies! I wonder which one is preferable:

> 1. After I'm done working I **will** have no plans, too. - or-
> 2. After I'm done working I have no plans, too.

Do I need a *will* word? Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you want to use "will"? Especially when learning English, it is best to leave out words that have no purpose.

Comment: @user3169 If OP is a learner there's no way they can know if the word has a purpose, if they did they would not ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need **will**, but there are multiple problems with both sentences.

Although I'm not certain what you are wanting to say, neither sentence is correct. The main problem is the relationship with time flow. Both sentences imply your lack of plans will not take place until you complete working. That is, you do not even plan to make a plan until your work is complete.

I'll choose a possible meaning just to be able to make a reply. It is a guess, though.

> When I complete work today, I don't know what I will be doing either.

One assumption is since you ended with "too", this is part of a conversation with a co-worker. He has stated he has no plans after work. Since you also lack plans (a negative), the proper ending word is **either**, not **too**. If you were both doing the same thing (a positive), **too** would be the right word.

- After work I am not going to the meeting **either**. [agreement with negated action]
- After work I need to go shopping **too**. [agreement with non-negated action]

Now to the front of the sentence. "When I complete work today" states very clearly what time frame you mean. "After I am done working" is way too broad. It could mean either end of the day's work or after retirement.

Finally, the phrase you actually asked about, "I [will] have no plans". Imagine it is 11 a.m., and work ends at 5. How do you know 6 hours from now you will still have no plans? What you do know is that right now, at 11, you have no plans. Since you have no plans **right now**. but the sentence began contemplating the future, it would sort of be a contradiction to talk about plans now.  That is why I changed to, "I don't know what I will be doing". This is something you can accurately state at 11.

If your point was to emphasize your lack of plans, then you could reverse the clauses:

> I have no plans for what to do after work today, either.

The sentence has not put itself into the future before you mention planning. Note that you would not say, "I **will** have no plans for ...". This is again because you are describing the present during that part of the sentence.

---

I hope you could follow all that, with all my assumptions and reformatting of your sentence. Sorry if I guessed wrong about what you meant.

Comment: All Right, you have explained everything well. I'll read it again to apply to my initial post :)

Comment: Using the word "will" in the sentence example the OP gave changes the sentence meaning to show a predicted future state. His prediction may or may not be accurate, but his accuracy when predicting the future is outside the scope of his question, which is how that word changes the meaning of the sentence.  I agree that the ending "too" is clumsy; I would replace "too" with "either" in his examples. If wants to be more precise as to the time, changing "done working" to "done working today" would work. The final sentence might be "After I'm done working today I have no plans either."

Comment: @MarkRipley Maybe I was loose with answering what I thought Sergey meant to say, rather than what he did say. It seemed more helpful to discuss a likely meaning rather than an unlikely one. I have problems with your last sentence though. As I tried to explain in my answer, how can he know at 11 whether he will have plans at 5? Maybe you mean people will understand that wording.  If so, I agree. That doesn't mean the tenses line up, though.